# Binding a property in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I'm trying to set up a property binding (WPF) in code. The code compiles fine, but the property I bind is never set. Below follows a minimal example:

The view-model:

```
public class FooViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _value;
    public string Value 
    { 
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}
```

The view:

```
public class FooView: Window
{
    public string Value
    {
        get { return Title; }
        set
        {
            // Breakpoint here never hits!
            Title = value;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(FooView));

    public FooView()
    {
        Binding valueBinding = new Binding("Value");
        valueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        SetBinding(ValueProperty, valueBinding);
    }
}
```

The "main()":

```
        FooView view = new FooView();
        FooViewModel model = new FooViewModel();
        view.DataContext = model;
        view.Show();
        model.Value = "ABC";
```

I expected the `FooView.Value`-setter to be invoked when `model.Value` is set. I've also tried explicitly setting the `Binding.Source` property to the model. How should the binding be set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Value` property is completely unrelated to the `ValueProperty` dependency property.

The CLR wrapper for a dependency property needs to call the DependencyObject's [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods like below:

```
public string Value
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}
```

In order to get notified about property changes, you would have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) with the [PropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.PropertyMetadata.aspx):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(string), typeof(FooView),
        new PropertyMetadata(ValuePropertyChanged));

private static ValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // obj is your FooView instance
    // get new property value from e.NewValue
}
```

Get more information in [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 from me. I didn't see that he setup his `dependency property` all wrong.

Comment: This works, thank you. Is dependency properties the correct way of binding a view-field (`FooView.Value`) to a model property (`FooViewModel.Value`) before the data context has been set, or is there a simpler way to do this? All I want to achieve is to keep `FooView.Value` in sync with any *future* viewmodel/data context.

Comment: I can't think of many other ways to *bind* a property. The target of a WPF binding has to be a dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `Source` property:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Value");
myBinding.Source = TheSourceOfTheProprty;
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
myBinding.IsAsync = false;

BindingOperations.SetBinding(YourControl, YourControl.Property, myBinding);
```

After fixing your `Dependency Property` like Clemens explained, then you just need to setup your binding and you will good to go.

So your binding with look like this:

```
FooViewModel model = new FooViewModel();

FooView view = new FooView(model);
view.DataContext = model;
view.Show();
model.Value = "ABC";


public FooView(FooViewModel model)
{
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("Value");
    myBinding.Source = model;
    myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, this.Value, myBinding);
}
```

Comment: I've also tried changing the `FooView` constructor to react to `DataContextChanged` and setting up a binding using your code (setting `Source` to the new model provided by the `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs`), but this does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: @larsm I am reading through your code now, but it seems wrong. Your `DependencyProperty` seems to be set up wrong. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make `FooView.Value` to be set whenever I set `FooViewModel.Value`.

Comment: @larsm See Clemens's answere.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you are about to set the title property of your fooview window from code behind. if so then you can use thexe binding lines  under your fooview constructor

```
 Binding valueBinding = new Binding("Value");
valueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
SetBinding(TitleProperty, valueBinding);|
```

Comment: Yes, but setting `Title` was only a way to see if the `Value`-setter was called, not something I actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: you can achive by simple putting value's propertyvaluechangedcallback